# Combining two dataframes and increasing count for common entries

Tags: r

I have two dataframes which I have computed after wrangling the data, and I am stuck on how to combine them. I have tried to recreate the scenario below:

The first dataframe d1:

```
player <- c("Ace", "Ace", "Ace", "Ace")
champ <- c("Azir", "Kassadin", "Xerath", "Zed")
games.played <- c(1, 2, 1, 1)
d1 <- data.frame(player, champ, games.played)
```

Which looks something like this:

```
player  champ   games.played
-------------------------
Ace     Azir         1
Ace     Kassadin     2
Ace     Xerath       1
Ace     Zed          1
```

The second dataframe d2:

```
player <- c("Ace", "Ace", "Ace", "Ace")
champ <- c("Chogath", "Karthus", "Victor", "Xerath")
games.played <- c(1, 1, 1, 2)
d2 <- data.frame(player, champ, games.played)
```

Which looks something like this:

```
player  champ   games.played
-------------------------
Ace     Chogath     1
Ace     Karthus     2
Ace     Viktor      1
Ace     Xerath      1
```

My desired output is (ordering is not really relevant):

```
player  champ   games.played
-------------------------
Ace     Azir         1
Ace     Kassadin     2
Ace     Xerath       3
Ace     Zed          1
Ace     Chogath      1
Ace     Karthus      1
Ace     Victor       1
```

Here's the catch, if there exists a pair of player and champ which exists in both the dataframes, I want to just add the number of games played. Otherwise, just add the pair which does not exist.

The closest I have gotten so far is by using `rbind(d1, d2)` which gives me the below output:

```
player    champ     games.played
-------------------------
Ace       Azir      1
Ace       Kassadin  2
Ace       Xerath    1
Ace       Zed       1
Ace       Chogath   1
Ace       Karthus   1
Ace       Victor    1
Ace       Xerath    2
```

My actual data frames are much bigger, so I cannot go about manually checking for duplicate rows and the individually combining them and adding the games.played. My actual dataframes are arranged by (player, champ) and that's why the scenario I have created is sorted so. Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: Try `aggregate(games.played~., rbind(d1, d2), sum)`  or using `dplyr` `bind_rows(d1, d2) %>% group_by(player, champ) %>% summarise(games.played = sum(games.played))`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! The aggregate solution did work, however, the dplyr solution gave the following error:
`Warning messages:
1: In bind_rows_(x, .id) : Unequal factor levels: coercing to character
2: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
  binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
3: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
  binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector `

Comment: You have `factor` columns.  So when it binded, the levels are different.  It is not an error but a friendly warning.  You can check the output, it will be the same as the aggregate output

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, could you put this as an answer so that I can close it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could `rbind` both the datasets, then do a group by and get the `sum` using `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(games.played~., rbind(d1, d2), sum)
```

---

A similar option with `dplyr` would be `bind_rows` with `group_by` and `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(d1, d2) %>% 
    group_by(player, champ) %>% 
    summarise(games.played = sum(games.played))
```